# Execute node http-server locally from cli

Tags: node.js, npm

If I install http-server locally (without -g flag) how can I run it with local directory as root directory?

In my root project directory I have a node_modules folder, If I want to execute http-server I need to execute $node ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server.

I wish to launch http-server with a command like $npm http-server.... If I use $npm start http-server, the server start without ./ as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the executable that sits in the module's bin folder like so:

```
> ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
```

If you want to do it with an npm command, you can put that in your package.json's scripts collection:

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Then you can just run

```
> npm start
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew this solution but I thought that another solution was more elegant. Anyways, if there is no any other solution I'll accept your answer.